# Abnormal beheviour of sqrt() in c while using in printf()

Tags: c

I am new to programming. I was finding a square root of a number using `sqrt()`function in c. `

```
        scanf("%d", &n);

        printf("%d\n", sqrt(n));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I enter a value of `n = 5`, I got some negative large number. Can anyone explain, please?

Comment: sqrt returns a double. Try `%f` instead of `%d`.

Comment: Also, the sqrt man page:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/sqrt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've produced undefined behavior by passing the wrong type to `printf`: the `%d` format required a matching argument of type `int` but your argument has type `double`. You need `%f` (or `%e` or `%g` or `%a`) to print it. Also, there may be other problems, e.g. if you omitted `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: Without `#include <math.h>`, when using `sqrt(n)` the `int n` won't be converted to `double`, because (if it compiles) the compiler will assume that `sqrt()` takes and returns an `int`.

Comment: Are you sue `%f`? or `%lf`?

Comment: @A.S.H the format spec `%lf` is for `scanf()` and friends to input a `double`.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, printf takes any %f as double, and converts any param if it is a float. But for good practice, since the OP must be aware that what he gets out of sqrt is actually a double.

Comment: @A.S.H in `printf()` the `l` is optional since `float` is promoted to `double` in variadic arguments. Format `%f` is for `double`.

Comment: I agree, but I always try to be explicit wherever I can. So I wonder if it is good practice to count on this implicit behavior. but anyway :)

Comment: It's funny how C looks strongly typed most of the time, while in some aspects it looks just like visual basic.

Comment: @A.S.H I would not consider C a strongly typed language. C has types, but they aren't strongly enforced.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the problem here is that the format specifier is wrong.  You need to `#include <math.h>` to get the proper return type of `sqrt()`, then use a format specifier like `%f`.  Also, turn up your compiler warnings until it tells you something was wrong here.  `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-system-headers` is a good choice.

I’m adding an answer, though, to provide historical background on why `float` variables get promoted to `double` in `printf()` argument lists, but not `scanf()`, since this confused people in the comments.

In the instruction set of the DEC PDP-10 and PDP-11 computers, on which C was originally developed, the `float` type existed only to save space, and a program needed to convert a `float` to `double` to do any calculations on it.  In early versions of C, before ANSI function prototypes, all `float` arguments to a function were promoted to `double` automatically before being passed (and also `char` to `int`).  Originally, this ran better at a low level, and also had the advantage of avoiding round-off and overflow error on math using the shorter types.  This convention also simplified writing functions that took a varying number of arguments of varying types, such as `printf()`.  The caller could just pass anything in, the compiler would let it, and it was the called function’s job to figure out what the argument list was supposed to be at runtime.

When C added function prototypes, these old rules were kept for backward-compatibility only with legacy function declarations (`extern double sqrt()` rather than `extern double sqrt(double)` or the C14 generic equivalent).  Since basically nobody writes functions that way any more, this is a historic curiosity—with one exception.  A `varargs` function like `int printf(const char*, ...);` *cannot* be written in C with type checking of the variable arguments.  (There is a C++14 way to do this using templates.)  The standards committee also did not want to break all existing code that printed a `float`.  So those are still promoted according to the old rules.

In `scanf()`, none of this applies because the storage arguments are passed by reference, and `scanf()` needs to be sure it’s writing the data in the same type as the variable that holds it.  Argument-promotion never comes into play, because only pointers are ever passed.

Comment: Nice historical overview. Like it. Notice that in my comment above, i was not contesting the fact that %f will work, but since in my practice i always prefer explicit coding, I wanted to raise the question whether using %f for doubles should be questionable practice these days, it seems that some mates use it systematically. Dunno :)

Comment: I notice also that recently I had some trouble with 64 longs, when I had to change many variable in some application, and i had to change so many traces from %d to %lld. I lost a lot of time. wish it was handlled the same way!

Comment: @A.S.H This is one time when the C++ standard library holds up better.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem. And I want to get an answer with `int` type. I use forced type conversion, like:

`printf("%d\n", (int)sqrt(n));`

Answer (score 0):

this is happens because return type and input type of the sqrt() is not specified ,
you can solve this by either including the header file by :

```
#include<math.h>
```

or by explicitly specifying the return and input type like this :

```
double sqrt(double);
```

and also as mentioned above use correct format specifiers (eg : %f) .